# How can I change the selected date text-color in a Datechooser?

Tags: apache-flex, datechooser

I'm trying to change the selected date **text-color**.

```
<fx:Style>

.dateChooser{
            selection-color:#000000;
        }

</fx:Style>`
```

I changed my selected date (FEB 23) selection-color to black, but I also need to change the text-color, let's say to white.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can checkout the colorful datechooser [here](http://code.google.com/p/flex-colorfuldatechooser/) .

Answer (score 0):

This article talks specifically about the `DateField` control, but you can probably use it for the `DateChooser` as well.

http://blog.flexexamples.com/2007/12/19/customizing-the-current-date-in-the-flex-datefield-control/